# Finding out the ethnicity of your DNA matches?

Tags: dna, ethnicity-dna

I've seen people discussing things like "I'm English but I have a bunch of Polish matches" with regard to DNA genealogy.

How exactly do you go about finding the ethnicity of your matches?

By emailing them only, looking at surnames, looking at family trees, etc.?

Comment: Hi Milena, welcome to G&FH SE. Is it possible to include a reference to an example of the discussion you're referring to? It's not really clear from your example whether they're referring to the nationality or ethnicity of the tester.

Comment: The answer to your question will be different depending on which DNA testing company the speaker is talking about.

Comment: MyHeritage DNA allows you to see the ethnicity estimates of your matches. I show an example in my blog post today about their new filtering features. http://www.beholdgenealogy.com/blog/?p=2630

Answer (score 2):

To see how I find out the ethnicity estimate for one of my matches at AncestryDNA try the following steps from its [front page](https://www.ancestry.com.au/):

1. Click on the **DNA** tab at the top
2. Click **View All DNA Matches**
3. Click the name of one of your matches
4. Click on the **Ethnicity** tab

You should see an estimate of your and their ethnicity compared:

[image]